# hide certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority popup

Tags: windows, group-policy, remote-desktop

I have device which, each time someone uses rdp causes "certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority" error, it's bug and producer is going to fix it in one of future relesases, but for now I wonder is there any way to hide that popup?

[image]

I want to connect anyway without user clicking "yes" button, or even seeing that communicate.

Is it possible to configure windows RDP client to not show that popup? If so, is it possible to do it using GPO?

Comment: It may be, but IMO that sounds like a particularly bad idea! The proper way is to replace the certificate. The next best is to trust the certificate authority that issued the cert on your PC. IMO suppressing the security message is highly likely to mean the proper fix never comes (or gets dragged out) and without it it is insecure and vulnerable to malicious attack.

Answer (score 1):

You can click the box that says **Don't ask me again for this computer**. In general though I don't think disabling these warnings is a good idea.

You can import the certificate to the trusted root certificate store on the PC that would prevent the message from popping up.

You can get a copy of the certificate and distribute it to the root store on all your PC's using a GPO.

Comment: Have the same problem but importing the certificate to the trusted certificate root store on the PC does not work (no effect). Haven't try GPO yet.